# Update a partial in rails with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html-select

I'm currently trying to create a simple drop-down list which takes a name and phone number, and then when you click on the selected option it updates anoher partial on the page with children objects of the selected option you have entered using Ajax.

i.e. if you choose `User1 | 555-555-5555` from the drop-down menu, you should get back a list of all reportapprovals from User1 in the 2nd partial.

I know this is a simple question but I'm not quite sure how to write the JavaScript to make it work.

Here's my code for the drop-down list partial:

Drop Down View:

```
<select id="adminDropDown" onchange= "chooseManager();" class="form-control">
  <% if current_admin.manager_approvals.blank? %>
    <option>No Sub-Accounts added, Add one today!</option>
  <% elsif current_admin.manager_approvals.all? { |ma| ma.manager_approved == false }%>
    <option>No Sub-Accounts approved yet!</option>
  <% else %>
    <% current_admin.manager_approvals.where(manager_approved: true).each do |ma| %>
      <option value="<%= ma.id %>"><%= ma.manager_company %>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<%= number_to_phone(ma.manager_phone) %></option>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

My controller looks like this...

```
class Admins::ReportapprovalsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @reportapprovals = Reportapproval.all(table:params[:table], per_table: 4)
  end

  def show
    @reportapproval = Reportapproval.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

2nd list partial...

```
report_list.html.erb
 ....
      <tbody>
        <% if @selected_manager_approval.reportapprovals.blank? %>
         <tr>
          <td width="100%">No reports available</td>
         </tr>
        <% else %>
          <% @selected_manager_approval.reportapprovals.each do |ra| %>
              <% if ra.report.present? %>
                <tr>
                    <td width="25%"><%= ra.tenant_last_name.truncate(17) %></td>
                    <td width="25%"><%= number_to_phone(ra.tenant_phone) %></td>
                    <td width="25%"><%= ra.date_approved %></td>
                    <td width="25%"><%= link_to "View Report", {:controller => "admins/reports", :action => "show", :id => ra.report_id}, :method => :get, class: "btn-default btn-sm" %></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

My js file...

```
$(chooseManager() {
  $('#adminDropDown')change(chooseManager() {
    value = $(this).val()
    $.post("admins/reportapprovals/manager_select", {manager_id: value}, chooseManager(data) );
  })
})
```

UPDATE-This js file gives me this error

```
 SyntaxError: [stdin]:6:5: unexpected (
```

How do I select one of the drop-down menu options and the refresh the 2nd partial? Right now the selected value should pass the instance ID as "@selected_manager_approval" to the 2nd partial and then automatically refresh ONLY the 2nd partial on the page? How should I do this?

Comment: You mean on change of the 'adminDropDown', you want that 'report_list.html.erb' should be refreshed with Reportapproval records where manager_id is  equivalent to the value of the drop-down ?

Comment: Yes,that is exactly what i am trying to do. Based on what I'm reading I need to use Ajax because it makes a call to the database after the dropdown is selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller add an action like this:

```
class Admins::ReportapprovalsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @reportapprovals = Reportapproval.all(table:params[:table], per_table: 4)
  end

  def show
    @reportapproval = Reportapproval.find(params[:id])
  end

  def manager_select
    @selected_manager_approval = ManagerApproval.find(params[:manager_approval_id])       
  end
end
```

In app/views/admins/report_approvals create manager_select.js.erb and add following code in that file.

```
// reportlist_wrapper_div_id is just an example you have to replace this with id of the div where you are rendering report_list partial.

$('#reportlist_wrapper_div_id').html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial =>"report_list")%>');
```

Change your chooseManager function like this:

```
chooseManager = ->
  managerApprovalId = $(this).val()
  $.ajax
    type: 'POST'
    url: 'admins/reportapprovals/manager_select'
    data: manager_approval_id: managerApprovalId
  return
```

Comment: I did this but since this is rails I keep getting errors about ````SyntaxError: [stdin]:8:1: reserved word 'function'```` After reading a little I need this function in coffeescript, how should I change it?

Comment: I have changed the function. Please check now

Comment: Still having trouble, this manager_select.js.erb file goes in the assets folder correct? not the views?

Comment: I am getting the error ````Uncaught ReferenceError: chooseManager is not defined```` in the console when I try and select from the dropdown menu

Comment: No, I have mentioned that manager_select.js.erb will be in app/views/admins/report_approvals folder

Comment: Ok, I have added the file but I still get the error ````Uncaught ReferenceError: chooseManager is not defined```` in the console when I try and select from the dropdown menu. Why wouldnt it find the function. I see that the function's file is loaded based on the page source

Comment: I got past this part. I needed to use @chooseManager to get past the scope?!

Comment: Finally got it, and I see what you were saying about the added view file Thanks!